# Spring + Thymeleaf binding form NullpointerException

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm currently working on an user edit form.

I have a user object with the following structure (pseudo code):

```
User

String name,
int age,
Address adress,
Email email,
User child,

getter/setter
```

Now, this object i put in as object in a `Model` like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUserByLogin(@PathVariable("login") final String login) {
    final User currentUser = UserRepository.findPersonByLogin(login);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(URL_EDIT_USER);
    mav.addObject(MODEL_USER, currentUser);

    return mav;
}
```

in my template (i use thymeleaf) i bind these object like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{user.name}">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user.name}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{user.address.street}">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user.address.street}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{user.child.email.value}">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user.child.email.value}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{user.child.address.street}">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user.child.address.street}" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

In the GET-Method the template/html shows the correct data i expected. Now i edit the fields and submit the form, then i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.user.model.Email.hashCode(EMail.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.validation.FieldError.toString(FieldError.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractErrors.toString(AbstractErrors.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.BindException.getMessage(BindException.java:284) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

All fields are transmitted correctly unless the email field of the child-object.

I have no idea why the error occurs, the structure is the same, the data is valid and the funny thing is when I grab the child email element in a separate object goes it

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Email class:

```
@Entity(name="Email")
public class Email implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6891079722082340011L;

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Expose
    protected Long eMailId;
    @Expose
    protected String value;

    //getter/setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(obj instanceof EMail){
            return value.equals(((Email) obj).getValue());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return value.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The post method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateUser(@PathVariable("login") final String login, @ModelAttribute final User webUser) {
    final Person repoUser = personRepository.findPersonByLogin(login);
    repoUser.updateWith(webUser);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + URL_USERS_OVERVIEW);
}
```

Comment: post com.example.user.model.Email and EMail.java

Comment: sorry that was my fault. i have corrected the spelling the vocabulary for the code. the class EMail is the same like Email. i have the code on my job. i thinking it's depends on the annotation for hibernate. the classes i use for the controller are the same i use for the database (entities). tomorrow i will update the code.

Comment: can you add the post handling method as well, as you only have the get handling method

Comment: i have updated the code, check it out

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException is happening in your `Email.hashCode()` method. Looking at your code this could happen if `value` is null.

The template you posted doesn't include the `user.email.value` field, so this is most likely why it is null.

Either you need to add a field for the user email, or change the `hashCode` method so that it handles the null value.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I had a hashCode method, maybe auto-generated that was overriden in my entity code.